# Find and replace within same field

Tags: string, replace, sed, awk, split

I have a record with data like below:

0IAB20130926

1~CVBB2WD~ED000~~~1152~1~1273~mc0332~abc@mail.com~29~0~101~
1~CVBB2WD~ED000~~~1059~1~1274~mc0332~abc@mail.com~29~0~102~
1~CVBB2WF~ED000~~~~~~~~21~0~1~"val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7"
1~CVBB2WD~ED000~~~~~~~~21~0~1~"val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7"

9000027681

The first and last lines are the header and footer (starts with 0 and 9 respectively).
Data starts with 1~
Each line has various fields each seperated with ~ delimeter. Most of lines don't have any value in the 14th field(like 1st two lines) except for few records that has the value like "val1,val2,val3.." (like last two lines)
I need to find them using the position (14th) and need to replace with the null fileds that are in the position 4th,5th,6th,7th,8th. 
So my output should look like this:

0IAB20130926

1~CVBB2WD~ED000~~~1152~1~1273~mc0332~abc@mail.com~29~0~101~
1~CVBB2WD~ED000~~~1059~1~1274~mc0332~abc@mail.com~29~0~102~
1~CVBB2WF~ED000~val1~val2~val3~val4~val5~val6~val7~21~0~1
1~CVBB2WD~ED000~val1~val2~val3~val4~val5~val6~val7~21~0~1

9000027681

Comment: What is your attempt at solving this?

Comment: im able to get the string "val1,val2,val3.." using cat file |awk '/1\~/{print $0} ' |awk -F"~" '$14!="" {print $0}'|cut -d"~" -f14       I'm not sure how to replace with the null fields.

Comment: But how is `"val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7"` becoming `val1~val2~val3~val4~val5~val6~val7` ?

Comment: i mean to say that the "val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7" to be split based on the comma delimeter and need to replace with the T4,T5,T6,T7,T8...(these are the postions in the line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk should work:

```
awk -F'~' '/^1/ && $14!=""{gsub(/,/, "~", $14); $14=substr($14, 2, length($14)-2); 
           $0=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $14 OFS $11 OFS $12 OFS $13}1' OFS='~' file

0IAB20130926

1~CVBB2WD~ED000~~~1152~1~1273~mc0332~abc@mail.com~29~0~101~
1~CVBB2WD~ED000~~~1059~1~1274~mc0332~abc@mail.com~29~0~102~
1~CVBB2WF~ED000~val1~val2~val3~val4~val5~val6~val7~21~0~1
1~CVBB2WD~ED000~val1~val2~val3~val4~val5~val6~val7~21~0~1

9000027681
```